# Valid django form not saving

Tags: django, django-forms, validation

In my view for editing friends I'm checking if form is valid, and then save the form. But somehow the data are not updated. Why my updated form is not saved ? It is 100% valid, since I've checked it earlier.

My form :

```
class FriendForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict, maxlength=50)), label="First name")
    last_name = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict, maxlength=50)), label="Last name")
    pid = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\d{11}', max_length=11 ,widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict, maxlength=50)))
    image = forms.ImageField(label="Image", required=False)
    street = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=dict(attrs_dict, maxlength=50)), label="Street")
    number = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="House/flat number")
    code = forms.RegexField(regex=r'^\d{2}[-]\d{3}', max_length=6, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs=attrs_dict), label="Postal code")
    city = forms.CharField(widget=forms.TextInput, label="City")
```

The view :

```
def edit_friend(request, id):
    userprofile = UserProfile.objects.get(user=request.user)
    friend = get_object_or_404(Friend, id=id)
    if friend.friend_of.id!=userprofile.id:
        raise Http404 
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = FriendForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=friend)
        if form.is_valid(): 
            form.save()           
        return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('user_profile',))
    else:
        form = FriendForm(instance=friend)
    return render_to_response('user/data_operations/edit_friend.html', {
            'form':form, 'user':request.user,
            }, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Template :

```
<form method="post" action="." enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <table>           
        {{ form.as_table }}
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td>
                <input type="submit" class="submit" name="submit" value="Save" />
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

I'd need to see the full code for your form to really answer this (can you include it?) but here are some initial thoughts:

Is `FriendForm` a subclass of `django.forms.ModelForm`?  If so, there's no need to override the `save` method -- especially since all you're doing here is getting the returned new object, saving it (again), and returning it (again) -- additional processing with no additional benefit.

If `FriendForm` isn't a subclass of `ModelForm`, how is it bound to database data?  What class is it inheriting from?

---

**UPDATE:**
`ModelForms` aren't connected directly to the database -- they are a shortcut for creating HTML forms for interacting with database models -- i.e. classes inheriting from `django.models.Model`.  You do that by creating a `Meta` class within your `ModelForm`.

With a `ModelForm`, you don't need to manually specify the fields (django does that automatically for you) unless you want to override specific behaviors.  You *do* have to tell django which database Model you're like to use.  If you've already defined a database `Model`, use it; if not, try this:

```
# in models.py
from django import models

class Friend(models.Model):
    first_name = models.CharField( "see <http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/> to adjust your syntax" )
    ... your other fields ...


# in forms.py
from django.forms import ModelForm
from my_project.my_app.models import Friend

class FriendForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Friend
```

That's it! Now your `FriendForm` should work properly.  See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/modelforms/ for more information on using `ModelForm`s.

Alternatively, you don't need to use a `ModelForm` at all.  You could add the following `save` method to your existing `FriendForm`:

```
def save(self):
    if self.is_valid():
        from myproject.myapp.models import Friend
        new_friend = Friend(**self.cleaned_data)
        new_friend.save()
        return new_friend
```

... the essence here is that you're importing the `Friend` model, which encapsulates the database storage behaviors.  This is basically what the `ModelForm` creates automatically for you, but not as robust -- so I recommend using `ModelForm`.

Comment: The first solution doesn't change anything. Still updated data are not saved. With second solution problem is that in edit mode I'm not able to send instance to form since it's not a ModelForm.

Comment: I have an updated question with both methods : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3169274/forms-for-instances-not-saved

Answer (score 2):

sometimes, if you add decorators like @transaction.commit_on_success during development, it prevents saving the form if there is even a single error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be overriding your model fields with those form fields.
check [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/forms/modelforms/). Normally when you have a modelform all you need to do is define a meta class and pass the extra settings you need for that particular form (rendered fields, their widgets, their labels, etc).

Answer (score 0):

You should set action attribute for your form tag. And set url name in urls.py.

Like `<form action="{% url 'edit_friend' %}" method="post">`

urls.py:

(...'/some-edit-url/', views.edit_friend, name='edit_friend'),